# On Windows 10, Is there a way to change my password to a previous password?

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I'm using Windows 10. I want to change my password to a previously used password. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Most Windows 10 users have their Microsoft account linked and use it for sign-in and settings sync. The "cannot use an old password" limitation is mandated not by Windows 10 itself, but by Microsoft's account security policies (which are independent of your Windows 10 PC).

Assuming you are using a Microsoft account, it is currently possible to work around this annoying policy by taking advantage of the fact that Microsoft only remembers the last 5 password you have used. Therefore, you should be able to set your password to an older one if you change your password at least 5 times, then try to change it to your older password.

Another solution is to move to a local user account on your Windows 10 PC instead of a Microsoft account. Just create a new user on your PC and make sure you don't link it with a Microsoft account, then start using that user account. Windows 10 will not put any "old password" limits on that account.

If you are facing this issue and you are sure you aren't using a Microsoft account, then there is likely a group policy security setting in-place preventing you from changing your password. If your PC is a work PC, then it's likely a setting managed by the organization and you can't change it. If it's your own PC, you can try to change the password policy of your local PC. The policy in question is the "[Enforce password history](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/enforce-password-history)" policy setting.